# I want to transpose column to row

Tags: sql, sqlite

My statement is

```
SELECT 
    t1.Class, t1.c1 AS 'Number of Incidents', t2.s2 AS 'Total Number' 
FROM
    (SELECT Class, COUNT(*) AS c1 
     FROM Observations 
     GROUP BY Class) AS t1 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT Class, SUM(mycount) AS s2 
     FROM
         (SELECT Class, COUNT(*) AS mycount 
          FROM Observations 
          GROUP BY Class)) AS t2 ON t1.Class = t2.Class;
```

and the result is

```
Class | Number of Incidents | Total Number 
------+---------------------+--------------
A               1                 10 
B               1                NULL 
C               2                NULL 
D               4                NULL
E               2                NULL
```

Is there any function to convert Total Number to be in Class below E and 10 to be in Number of Incidents below 2?

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT Class, [Number of Incidents] 
FROM (
  SELECT Class, COUNT(*) AS [Number of Incidents], 1 pos 
  FROM Observations 
  GROUP BY Class
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Total Number', COUNT(*), 2
  FROM Observations 
)  
ORDER BY pos, Class
```